# Terminal: To copy a line of text to general macOS clipboard

Tags: terminal

In Terminal, to copy a line of text so that it can be pasted back later, one can use the kill-ring way:

1. Type the text you want to paste later
2. Press Control-U to delete the line
3. ...
4. Press Control-Y to yank (= paste) this text back

But there is a pitfall: using this method, you won't be able to paste this text to other apps, e.g., TextEdit or Keynote. That is, if you open TextEdit then, neither Command-V, nor Control-Y will paste this text there.

So, is it possible to copy a line of text in Terminal, using the keyboard only (that is, without selecting this text using the mouse or trackpad) so that it can be pasted not only in Terminal but also in TextEdit, Keynote, and other GUI apps?

Comment: You're mixing the emacs-like line editing commands your shell provides, with the system clipboard. provided through Terminal.app.  They don't talk to each other.  Googling around, it looks like `screen` or `tmux` might be a bridge.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  I don't use zsh.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336228/make-ctrl-k-in-terminal-copy-to-the-system-clipboard?rq=1

Comment: @MarcWilson Awesome, many thanks.